# Stuck in determining truth value using proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I need your advice/help regarding these questions.

**Q.** Let p(x,y) denotes the predicate x divides y. Determine truth value of each statement and give an example or a counter-example for the statements.

**1)** ∀x ∃y p(x,y)
**A.** I guess it is true, but I'm basically having difficulty in understanding how is it true?

My logic says that for example if we suppose x = 3 and y = 15 then y =15 can be divided by this x =3 and also x = 5 so it is true. But confusion is how this covers every x (How every x can divide y?)

**2)** ∀y ∃x p(x,y)
This looks false, but how?

**3)** ∃x ∀y p(x,y)
**A.** ?

**4)** ∃y ∀x p(x,y)
**A.**
?

I would appreciate if someone helps me in these questions.  I'm basically struggling the in the concept of For all x and for some y here in such questions.

EDIT: For Q.4 Answer:
(0 | 0 and 1 | 0 and 2 | 0 and 3 | 0 and 4 | 0 .....)
     ----------------OR----------------------------
(0 | 1 and 1 | 1 and 2 | 1 and 3 | 1 and 4 | 1 .....)
--------------------OR---------------------------
(0 | 2 and 1 | 2 and 2 | 2 and 3 | 2 and 4 | 2 .....)

So, First Row is False as 0 | 0 is false and similarly second and third row is also false so it makes the whole statement false.

Comment: 0|0 is undefined, not false.  Division by zero is undefined.

Comment: Oh! I see. So it means the first row is true as 0 can be divided by any number but second and third rows are false. At the end due to the first row, the whole statement becomes true. Is it correct bro?

Comment: It means the first row is undefined as (undefined and true) is undefined, so the overall expression is (undefined or false) which is undefined.  I said it was tricky ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \newcommand{\and} {~\text{and}~}
 \newcommand{\or} {~~\text{or}~~}
 \newcommand{\undef} {~~\text{undefined}~~}$$

Write the statements without quantifiers.  I'll be using $x|y$ to indicate that $x$ divides $y$, that is, that $y$ is divisible by $x$:

> **1)** $$\forall x \exists y ~ p(x,y)  $$

$$\begin{array} {c}
(0|0 \or 0|1 \or 0|2 \or 0|3 \dots )\\
\and \\
(1|0 \or 1|1 \or 1|2 \or 1|3 \dots )\\
\and \\
(2|0 \or 2|1 \or 2|2 \or 2|3 \dots )\\
\and \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

Division by zero is undefined.  Otherwise, each horizontal line has an expression of the form $n|n$ (the second line has $1|1$, the third has $2|2$, etc).  So the expression is:

$$\begin{array} {c}
(\undef \or \undef \or \undef \or \undef \dots )\\
\and \\
(1|0 \or \top \or 1|2 \or 1|3 \dots )\\
\and \\
(2|0 \or 2|1 \or \top \or 2|3 \dots )\\
\and \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

which is

$$\undef \and \top \and \top \dots$$

So the entire expression is undefined.

> **2)** $$\forall y \exists x ~ p(x,y)  $$

$$\begin{array} {c}
(0|0 \or 1|0 \or 2|0 \or 3|0 \dots )\\
\and \\
(0|1 \or 1|1 \or 2|1 \or 3|1 \dots )\\
\and \\
(0|2 \or 1|2 \or 2|2 \or 3|2 \dots )\\
\and \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

Although division by zero is undefined, zero is divisible by everything (as $0/x$ is always an integer, $0$).  Otherwise everything is divisible by itself:

$$\begin{array} {c}
(\undef \or \top \or \top \or \top \dots )\\
\and \\
(\undef \or \top \or 2|1 \or 3|1 \dots )\\
\and \\
(\undef \or 1|2 \or \top \or 3|2 \dots )\\
\and \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

which is:

$$\top \land \top \land \top \dots$$

which is true.

> **3)** $$\exists x \forall y ~ p(x,y)  $$

$$\begin{array} {c}
(0|0 \and 0|1 \and 0|2 \and 0|3 \and 0|4 \dots )\\
\or \\
(1|0 \and 1|1 \and 1|2 \and 1|3 \and 1|4 \dots )\\
\or \\
(2|0 \and 2|1 \and 2|2 \and 2|3 \and 2|4 \dots )\\
\or \\
(3|0 \and 3|1 \and 3|2 \and 3|3 \and 3|4 \dots )\\
\or \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

This time we look at how $n$ never divides $n + 1$, except when $n=1$, because $1$ divides everything:

$$\begin{array} {c}
(\undef \and \undef \and \undef \and \undef \and \undef \dots )\\
\or \\
(\top \and \top \and \top \and \top \and \top \dots )\\
\or \\
(2|0 \and 2|1 \and 2|2 \and \bot \and 2|4 \dots )\\
\or \\
(3|0 \and 3|1 \and 3|2 \and 3|3 \and \bot \dots )\\
\or \\
\vdots \\
\end{array}$$

Which is:

$$\undef \or \top \or \bot \or \bot \dots$$

which is true.  That one is pretty complicated.

> **4)** $$\exists y \forall x ~ p(x,y)  $$

Can you do this one?

Comment: Thank-you very much. For 4) I think it is false because we have to suppose y = any number, for example, y = 12 and now y will remain constant and it should have been divided by each x such as 0,1,-2,5,6,7,9, 4/3 etc. which is not possible. For example, we cannot divide y = 12 by x = 0, x = 5 etc. So, it is false. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Afraid not right.  This one is rather difficult.  Start by writing out the table of x|y and the "ands" and "ors" like I did.  You can edit your question to do it if you want.

Comment: Hey, I have edited the Q.4 answer the way you did. Can you tell me is it right or wrong and help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need most is a translation (from math into English).

1) For each given $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $x|y$ (try to find one).

2) For each given $y$ there exists an $x$ such that $x|y$ (try to find one).

3) There exists a value of $x$ that satisfies $x|y$ for each given $y$.

4) There exists a value of $y$ that satisfies $x|y$ for each given $x$.

Comment: Thank-you dude but If you don't mind telling me the answers and a little way how you prove its truth value. I have spent many hours and can easily understand if someone gives me the answers. I can guess, but I need to be confident with myself in proving this. Now I'm not confident

Comment: @GhostRider I'm not going to give you the answers, but I can help you prove each one. For the first one, play around with some values of $x$. What value of $y$ do you know you can choose that will necessarily make this true? (Does this help?)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question 1: that I suppose for all x, x = 3 and for some y, y = 15 then x can divide y. Also, x = 5 can divide y =15. But what about x = 1,2,4,7,8 etc.? they come under for all x , but don't divide y = 15. So it makes it false. Is it right? Thanks! Could you help me with other ones as well, if you don't mind?

Comment: @GhostRider It doesn't have to be the same $y$ for all of the $x$-s (that's problem $4$). For $x=4$, you could take $y=16$ if you wanted.

Comment: Yeah! so I think question 1 is false, by its counter example that if I suppose x = 0, then 0 cannot divide y = anything. So, even though I know that y = 16 can be divided by 4, but because I choose x =0 and it failed to divide y = any number. Is it right? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure whether $0$ should be included. Does the problem sheet say anything about $0$? It kills a lot of the problems but makes some more interesting. Also, does $0|0$? I don't know.

Comment: No, there is nothing there. No domain specifying.

Comment: @GhostRider In that case, even though it requires doing more, I would do each problem first under the assumption that $0$ is part of it, and second under the assumption that $0$ is not. Also, I have no idea whether $0|0$, although probably not.

Comment: Yeah, but let's ignore the zero. Once again dude providing answers will help me and others as well as I got the idea, but I will do it wrong in the future exam if I don't know. By your answers, I can easily clarify things in my mind. You look an expert and can help me if you like. It's up to you but do consider. Thanks!

Comment: Watch out with the phrasing "There exists a value of $x$ that satisfies $x\mid y$ for each given $y$." I could easily see it being read as both "There exists a value of $x$ that satisfies ($x\mid y$ for each given $y$)" and "(There exists a value of $x$ that satisfies $x\mid y$) for each given $y$."

Comment: @MeesdeVries Is it well-defined?